# How to send emoji via bash script to Telegram bot using curl?

Tags: bash, curl, telegram, emoji

I'm trying to send an emoji/emoticon to my Telegram bot using a bash script. This bash script calls the Telegram API as follows:

`curl -s -X POST 'https://api.telegram.org/'$API'/sendMessage' -F chat_id=$chat -F text=$text`

Since the bash script isn't unicode, I cannot simply copy/paste the emojis from the web. Therefore I tried using the UTF-8 emoji variants, but the backslash character keeps getting escaped.

The expected json output should be as follows: `"text":"\ud83d\udd14"`

Instead, this is what I get:

Input: `$text = \xF0\x9F\x98\x81`
JSON Output = `"text":"\\xF0\\x9F\\x98\\x81\\"`

Input: `$text = u'\U0001F604'`
JSON Output = `"text": "u'\\U0001F604'\"`

Input: `$text = \U0001F514`
JSON Output = `"text":"\\U0001F514"`

Input: `$text =  "(1f600)"`
JSON Output = `"text":"\"(1f600)\""`

Input: `$text = \ud83d\ude08`
JSON Output = `"text":"\\ud83d\\ude08"`

Input: `$text = \\\ud83d\\\udd14`
JSON Output = `"text":"\\\\\\ud83d\\\\\\udd14"`

What is the correct syntax to send an emoji using a bash script and curl to my Telegram bot?

Thank you very much!

Comment: If you're trying to generate JSON, let a tool written to handle JSON, like `jq`, figure out how to encode your string.

Comment: BTW, what do you mean, "the bash script isn't unicode"? If you need to fix your editor settings, that's a problem with your text editor's configuration, and can be fixed from there. UTF-8 is a perfectly valid encoding to use for your script itself.

Comment: Maybe I'm mixing things up, but I am using nano via SSH  on a stripped down Unix environment (Synology NAS). If i copy/paste an emoticon from the Web into my SSH session, I get two question marks as a result. Hence i thought it was an encoding issue.

Comment: Hmm. What terminal are you using for the SSH session? Are you sure *that's* UTF-8 capable, and using an appropriate font?

Comment: I am using Rebex, but it appears that the encoding was set to some ISO-xxxx standard. After switching it to utf 8, I am able to copy/paste emoticons, yet I still have to declare them as variable first for them to be processed properly (i.e. not getting escaped) by the telegram api.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Generating JSON For The Telegram API

If your question is about JSON encoding, let [**`jq`**](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/) figure it out for you:

```
s=''  ## or s=$'\360\237\224\224'

json=$(jq -anc --arg id "$chat" --arg s "$s" '{"chat_id": $id, "text": $s}')
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "$json" \
  "https://api.telegram.org/$API/sendMessage"
```

---

#### From JSON To String Literal

In bash 4.0 or newer, the shell itself can be asked to give you an ASCII-printable literal string which will correspond to a multi-byte character.

```
LC_ALL=C printf "s=%q\n" "$(jq -r . <<<'"\ud83d\udd14"')"
```

...will output:

```
s=$'\360\237\224\224'
```

---

#### From String Literal To JSON

To go in the other direction:

```
s=$'\360\237\224\224'
jq -anM --arg s "$s" '$s'
```

...emits as output:

```
"\ud83d\udd14"
```

Comment: How the bell did you post that bell?

Comment: @hek2mgl, I got the bell from `jq -r . <<<'"\ud83d\udd14"'`, consuming the literal JSON string the OP put in the question.

Comment: Many thanks for your super quick answer and example. I am going to try this out tomorrow. I am not sure if jq is installed on my environment, but if not I'll fall back to your second example. Thank you very much! I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: Hmm. If you don't have JQ, I'd be tempted to use Python rather than bash (since any remotely-recentish Python interpreter will have a JSON parser/generator built-in). That's doubly true if your messages are going to be coming from tooling that you don't directly control -- you don't need a text string ending in, say `", "sendVideo": "http://example.com/spam.m4v` to be able to create new JSON fields rather than being correctly escaped as data.

Comment: Many many thanks for your detailed answer! Both approaches worked (i.e. the `jq` approach and the 'convert to String Literal manually approach) for me. I spent almost 2 hours on getting something simple like this to work. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: Is there a way to have the emoji inside the string instead of a separate var? eg `json=$(jq -anc --arg id "$chat" --arg s "$'\360\237\224\224'" '{"chat_id": $id, "text": $s}'`

Comment: @Stormenet, that example would work fine if you didn't have double quotes around the [ANSI C-like string](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting#ansi_c_like_strings). Make it `--arg s $'\360\237\224\224'`

Comment: I wasn't clear with my intent, can we do this around existing text, something like `--arg s "This is an emoji: $'\360\237\224\224' and this is some more text..."` since the latter isn't working here.

Comment: @Stormenet `--arg s $'This is an emoji: \360\237\224\224 and this is some more text...'` -- or you can switch quoting styles within your string by ending the double quotes and starting the ANSI C-like string, then if you want to switch back to double quotes ending the C-like string and starting double quotes again. This isn't really a jq question, it's just about how quoting works in bash in general.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `echo -e '\U0001F514'` for get emoji

```
curl -F "text=`echo -e '\U0001F514'` - it's a bell" "https://api.telegram.org/$API/sendMessage?chat_id=$chat"
```

or `$'\U0001F514'`

```
curl -F "text="$'\U0001F514'" - it's a bell" "https://api.telegram.org/$API/sendMessage?chat_id=$chat"
```

Comment: thx @Geograph I was thinking the same as you by using "echo -e" and it worked for me.

Comment: Boo, hiss re: `echo -e`; even [the POSIX standard for `echo`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html) says to use `printf` instead (see the APPLICATION USAGE and RATIONALE sections). There's also an excellent answer on the [unix.se] question [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/65819/3113)