# Emojis Facebook Messenger - Pesisten menu

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, bots, git-bash

i’m have a question, i trying put emojis in a persistent menu for facebook Messenger someone knows how to upload them by code?

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
"persistent_menu":[
    {
        "locale":"default",
        "composer_input_disabled": true,
        "call_to_actions":[
            {
                "title":"Monkeys Bar Productos ",
                "type":"nested",
                "call_to_actions":}
```

I need put emojis in menu persistent

Answer (score 0):

You have an example in "[How to add a persistent menu to Facebook messenger bot](https://www.techiediaries.com/messenger-bot-persistent-menu/) "

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
"persistent_menu":[
...
} "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messenger_profile?access_token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN_HERE"
```

But if you are doing that in a git bash session on Windows, I would recommend [as in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21087438/6309):

- putting the JSON in a file (making sure to [use `\n`, not `\r\n`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7013341/6309) as [newlines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline))
- use `curl ... -d @json.txt`

That way, the all command is in one line, and you don't need to do some [complex escape as seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12498151/6309).

Comment: But how make for send emojis for comand line?. i try use unicode but not service.

Comment: @CRIS7HIAN30 Try the text form, UTF-8 encoded, with the unicode in it.

Comment: Don't fuction, i try UTF-8 :c

Comment: @CRIS7HIAN30 Just for testing, try with a test file UTF-8 encoded, but *without* any emoji. Would it work then?

Comment: I try send text whithout any emoji, and this succesful result

Comment: @CRIS7HIAN30 Then try again, with emoji, but using jq, as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/50009974/6309